# First integral of a system of ODEs

Tags: differential-equations

For the system $x' = y$ and $y' = -x + x^3 y$, I need to find the first integral. It can be written:

$$\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{y}{-x + x^3y}$$

How can I solve for the integral? Or maybe there is faster way to find first integral of the system?

Comment: One solution is: `{x[t]=0,y[t]=0}`.Try `NDSolve`.Probably  another closed-form solution not exist.

Comment: Is your question about solving these equations using the Mathematica software?  Or are you looking for an analytical solution?  If you're looking for mathematical techniques to solve this system, you would be better off posting this to [Math.SE] instead.

Answer (score 3):

*(Extended comment, not an answer.)*

Try using [`DSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html) and / or [`NDSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html).

```
sol = DSolve[D[x[y], y] == y/(-x[y] + x[y]^3 y), x[y], y]

(* DSolve[Derivative[1][x][y] == y/(-x[y] + y x[y]^3), x[y], y] *)

sol = DSolve[1/D[y[x], x] == y[x]/(-x + x^3 y[x]), y[x], x]

(* Solve[(
   x^2 AiryAi[x^4/4 - y[x]] + 2 AiryAiPrime[x^4/4 - y[x]])/(
   x^2 AiryBi[x^4/4 - y[x]] + 2 AiryBiPrime[x^4/4 - y[x]]) + C[1] == 
  0, y[x]] *)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think both x and y depend on a variable, let's call it t, that is x[t] and y[t].

The dx/dy you are looking for is the same as (dx/dt)/(dy/dt), where dt cancel. In Mathematica you can do this with the total differential `Dt`  .

```
differential = Dt[x[t]]/Dt[y[t]]

(*   Derivative[1][x][t]/Derivative[1][y][t]   *)

sol = Solve[{x'[t] == y[t], y'[t] == -x[t] + x[t]^3 y[t]}, {x'[t], 
             y'[t]}]

differential /. First@sol 

(*   y[t]/(-x[t] + x[t]^3 y[t])   *)
```